# How to change iBeacon broadcast frequency and power level on Asus USB-BT400

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, frequency

I'm trying to change iBeacon broadcasting frequency on Asus USB-BT400. Currently it is 1Hz (tested on wireshark) and I want to change it to >10Hz. Even though it uses the same chipset as IOGear GBU521 (Broadcom BCM20702A0) there must be some differences between the two because the code (working on IOGear) doesn't work on Asus:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 01
```

Also, in similar manner, the power level cannot be changed this way. Maybe the command structure for Asus is different?

Comment: I assume you have experimented with different values instead of the A0 00 A0 00 in the command above, and it has made no change in what you see on Wireshark?

Comment: Yes and there were no results, meaning it still sent beacons once every second.